# Is a finite field matrix treated the same as normal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

Do I bring a finite field matrix to RREF the same way as a real number matrix, or do I have to follow the finite field addition and multiplication operations

Comment: You have to follow the arithmetic of the field you're in. Normally you would work in the field $\mathbb{R}$ of the real numbers. Now that you have changed fields, you must change the arithmetic accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found out, it follows the finite field operations